# Return only video type (extension) by ffmpeg

Tags: curl, command-line, ffmpeg, command

I'm developing an converter service and I use **FFMPEG** to convert videos.

I want to check input files, which kind of really is video.

I used following command and get file type. But if the file has been manipulated It can not understand:

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{content_type}" ${url}
```

I really want to just get video type by ffmpeg.

can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way for this problem. *(This is a trick)*

If be passed to **FFMPEG** a manipulated video file, it throw an error.
Then I used following command:

> ffprobe -i http://uploadserver.ln/1.mp4 -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"

This command give video duration. If the video file has been manipulated, you will get Null result. Otherwise you get video duration.

Comment: Note that this will give false negative for raw video bitstreams, like `.h264`

Comment: thank you. but i am not working with stream videos. @Gyan

Comment: Do you know how to do this? can you help me ? @Gyan